# New Node V8 Inspector not logging to console on Windows PC

Tags: node.js, windows, v8, inspector

On my Windows PC I have the latest version of node 6.9.1 which has V8 inspector built in. When I use the --inspect flag to run an app.js file and go to the "chrome-devtools" URL to attach the Debugger, everything works fine (I can set breakpoints and step through the code) but console.log code doesn't print to the chrome console. I already checked the console filter, it is set to ALL. It prints to the console window where I ran the app, just not to Chrome.

I have Windows Server 2008 R2. I dont have this issue on my macbook, it logs to the chrome console fine. I was hoping someone could check if they have it working on their Windows computer or if anybody else has run into this issue. Maybe its just a Server 2008 R2 issue?

It is very easy to test. Just create an app.js file with 1 line "console.log('test')", open command prompt or git Bash or whatever in the folder and type:

node --inspect --debug-brk app.js

It will give you a chrome-devtools URL. Go to this URL in chrome and you will see your app. The script execution will be stopped (due to the -brk flag) so you will have to resume it. If you have the same issue as me, you will notice that when you resume it, nothing will be logged to console.

Comment: I have the same question for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. ( `Node 6.11.0`, `V8 Inspector` and no console)

I've updated `Node.js` to version 8.9.0 for Windows

I've downloaded the msi file [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Now everything it's OK.